# Why cython code takes more time than python code to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, cython

I have a function that takes 2 images and a variable, inside function there are several opencv and numpy operations inside loops, when I run it in python with just replacing lists with numpy arrays it takes 0.36 sec to run and when I convert it to cython, it takes 0.72 sec to run
first question : is it normal and then should I try multithread or multiprocess in this case?
second question : in overal I read images from disk or camera should I use both multithread and multiprocess?

here's my code structure in both python and cython :
python :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


def p_matching_v6(image_fov_11, image_fov_22, av_min_tr2):
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    if image_fov_11.dtype == np.uint8:
        im1gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_fov_11, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        im2gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_fov_22, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    else:
        im1gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_fov_11, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        im2gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_fov_22, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    shp = 1024    # shape of array
    refy1 = np.zeros((1024,), dtype='float64')
    refy2 = np.zeros((1024,), dtype='float64')
    ref1 = np.zeros((1024,), dtype='float64')
    ref11 = np.zeros((1024,), dtype='float64')
    ref2 = np.zeros((1024,), dtype='float64')
    refx1 = np.zeros((1024,), dtype='float64')
    refx2 = np.zeros((1024,), dtype='float64')

    retval, im1 = cv2.threshold(im1gray, av_min_tr2, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    retval, im2 = cv2.threshold(im2gray, av_min_tr2, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    rngc = int(shp / 2)
    rngr = int(shp / 2)

    sum_c1 = np.zeros(shp)  ##sum of the elements of each column of the first image
    sum_c2 = np.zeros(shp)  ##sum of the elements of each column of the second image
    sum_r1 = np.zeros(shp)  ##sum of the elements of each row of the first image
    sum_r2 = np.zeros(shp)  ##sum of the elements of each row of the second image

    sum_c1 = np.sum(im1 == 0, axis=0)
    sum_c2 = np.sum(im2 == 0, axis=0)
    sum_r1 = np.sum(im1 == 0, axis=1)
    sum_r2 = np.sum(im2 == 0, axis=1)

    amc1 = np.argmax(sum_c1)  # argmax sum_c1
    amr1 = np.argmax(sum_r1)  # argmax sum_r1

    ## Dy
    y1 = np.zeros((1, 11))
    z1 = np.zeros((1, 11))
    r2 = np.zeros((rngc, 2))

    refy1[:], refx1[:] = im1gray[:, amc1], im1gray[amr1, :]

    refy1 -= np.sum(refy1) / shp  # normalize
    refx1 -= np.sum(refx1) / shp # normalize

    ## The selected column in the first half of the image 1
    if amc1 <= rngc:
        amch1 = np.argmax(sum_c2[:rngc])  # argmax nime aval im2

        refy2[:] = im2gray[:, amch1]  # second image
        refy2 -= np.sum(refy2) / shp # normalize

        r1 = np.zeros((amc1 + rngc, 2))
        for i in range(amc1 + rngc):
            ref1[:] = im2gray[:, i]
            ref1 -= np.sum(ref1) / shp # normalize

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

        for i in range(rngc):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

    else:  # amc1 > rngc
        amch2 = rngc + np.argmax(sum_c2[rngc:])  # argmax nime dovom im2
        refy2[:] = im2gray[:, amch2]  # second image
        refy2 -= np.sum(refy2) / shp # normalize
        xx = shp - (amc1 - rngc)
        r1 = np.zeros((xx, 2))
        for i in range(xx):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

        for i in range(rngc):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

    if min_y1 < min_y2:
        min_y = min_y1
        dy = dy1
        dy_x = ry_x1
    else:
        min_y = min_y2
        dy = dy2
        dy_x = ry_x2

    ## Dx
    r2 = np.zeros((rngr, 2))
    if amr1 <= rngr:
        amrh1 = np.argmax(sum_r2[:rngr])  # argmax nime aval im2
        refx2[:] = im2gray[amrh1, :]  # second image
        refx2 -= np.sum(refx2) / shp # normalize
        r1 = np.zeros((amr1 + rngr, 2))

        for i in range(amr1 + rngr):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .
            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .
            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

        for i in range(rngr):
            .
            .
            .
            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .
            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .
            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

    else:  # amr1 > rngr
        amrh2 = rngr + np.argmax(sum_r2[rngr:])  # argmax nime dovom im2
        refx2[:] = im2gray[amrh2, :]  # second image
        refx2 -= np.sum(refx2) / shp # normalize
        yy = shp - (amr1 - rngr)
        r1 = np.zeros((yy, 2))

        for i in range(yy):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

        for i in range(rngr):
            .
            .
            .
            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

    if min_x1 < min_x2:
        min_x = min_x1
        dx = dx1
        dx_y = rx_y1
    else:
        min_x = min_x2
        dx = dx2
        dx_y = rx_y2

    D = min(min_x, min_y)
    if D == min_x:
        Dx = dx
        Dy = dx_y

    elif D == min_y:
        Dy = dy
        Dx = dy_x

    return int(Dx), int(Dy)
```

cython :

```
import cython
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport openmp
from cython.parallel cimport prange
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray
import cv2
from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


np.import_array()
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef tuple p_matching_v6(unsigned char[:,:] im1gray, unsigned char[:,:] im2gray, int av_min_tr2):
    cdef unsigned char[:, :] im1 = im1gray
    cdef unsigned char[:, :] im2 = im2gray
    cv2.threshold(np.asarray(im1gray), av_min_tr2, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, np.asarray(im1))
    cv2.threshold(np.asarray(im2gray), av_min_tr2, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, np.asarray(im2))
    cdef int rngc = im1gray.shape[1] // 2
    cdef int rngr = im2gray.shape[0] // 2

    # # Otsu's thresholding
    cdef int im1_shape0 = im1gray.shape[0]
    cdef int im1_shape1 = im1gray.shape[1]
    cdef int im2_shape0 = im2gray.shape[0]
    cdef int im2_shape1 = im2gray.shape[1]
    cdef int[:] sum_c1 = np.zeros(im1_shape1, dtype=np.int32)
    cdef int[:] sum_c2 = np.zeros(im2_shape1, dtype=np.int32)
    cdef int[:] sum_r1 = np.zeros(im1_shape0, dtype=np.int32)
    cdef int[:] sum_r2 = np.zeros(im2_shape0, dtype=np.int32)


    ## find of max zeros in column
    cdef int j, i, g, ayf, temp_y1, dy1, ays, temp_y2, dy2, amch2, amch1, amc1, amr1
    for j in range(im1_shape1):
        sum_c1[j] = im1_shape0 - cv2.countNonZero(np.asarray(im1[:, j]))
    amc1 = np.argmax(sum_c1)
    for j in range(im2_shape1):
        sum_c2[j] = im2_shape0 - cv2.countNonZero(np.asarray(im2[:, j]))

    for j in range(im1_shape0):
        sum_r1[j] = im1_shape1 - cv2.countNonZero(np.asarray(im1[j, :]))
    amr1 = np.argmax(sum_r1)

    for j in range(im2_shape0):
        sum_r2[j] = im2_shape1 - cv2.countNonZero(np.asarray(im2[j, :]))

    ## Dy
    cdef Py_ssize_t xx
    cdef double x1 = 0, byf, min_y1, ry_x1, x2 = 0, bys, min_y2, ry_x2,
    cdef double[:, ::1] ry1, ry2
    cdef double[::1] y1 = np.empty(11, dtype=np.float64)
    cdef double[:, ::1] r2 = np.empty((rngc, 2), dtype=np.float64)
    cdef int[::1] z1 = np.empty(11, dtype=np.int32)


    cdef double[::1] refy1, refy2, ref1, ref2
    refy1 = np.empty(im1gray.shape[0], dtype=np.float64)
    refy2 = np.empty(im2gray.shape[0], dtype=np.float64)
    cdef double[:, ::1] r1
    if amc1 <= rngc:
        amch1 = np.argmax(sum_c2[:rngc])  # argmax nime aval im2
        refy1 = np.asarray(im1gray[:, amc1]).astype('float64')  # first image
        refy1 = refy1 - np.average(refy1)  # normalize
        refy2 = np.asarray(im2gray[:, amch1]).astype('float64')  # second image
        refy2 = refy2 - np.average(refy2)  # normalize
        r1 = np.empty((amc1 + rngc, 2), dtype=np.float64)
        for i in range(amc1 + rngc):
            x1 = 0
            ref1 = np.asarray(im2gray[:, i]).astype('float64')
            ref1 = ref1 - np.average(ref1)
            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .


        for i in range(rngc):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

    else:  # amc1 > rngc
        amch2 = rngc + np.argmax(sum_c2[rngc:])  # argmax nime dovom im2
        refy1 = np.asarray(im1gray[:, amc1]).astype('float64')  # first image
        refy1 = refy1 - np.average(refy1)  # normalize
        refy2 = np.asarray(im2gray[:, amch2]).astype('float64')  # second image
        refy2 = refy2 - np.average(refy2)  # normalize
        xx = im1gray.shape[1] - (amc1 - rngc)
        r1 = np.empty((xx, 2))
        for i in range(xx):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

        for i in range(rngc):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .


        .
        .
        .

    cdef double min_y,
    cdef double[:,:] ry
    cdef int dy, dy_x

    if min_y1 < min_y2:
        min_y = min_y1
        ry = ry1
        dy = dy1
        dy_x = int(ry_x1)
    else:
        min_y = min_y2
        ry = ry2
        dy = dy2
        dy_x = int(ry_x2)

    ## Dx
    cdef int amrh1, axf, temp_x1, dx1, axs, temp_x2, dx2, amrh2
    cdef Py_ssize_t yy
    cdef double a1 = 0, bxf, min_x1, a2 = 0, bxs, min_x2, rx_y2, rx_y1
    cdef double[:,:] rx1
    cdef double[:,:] rx2
    cdef double[:] refx1, refx2
    r2 = np.empty((rngr, 2))

    if amr1 <= rngr:
        amrh1 = np.argmax(sum_r2[:rngr])  # argmax nime aval im2
        refx1 = np.asarray(im1gray[amr1, :]).astype('float64')  # first image
        refx1 = refx1 - np.average(refx1)  # normalize
        refx2 = np.asarray(im2gray[amrh1, :]).astype('float64')  # second image
        refx2 = refx2 - np.average(refx2)  # normalize
        r1 = np.empty((amr1 + rngr, 2))
        for i in range(amr1 + rngr):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

        for i in range(rngr):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .


    else:  # amr1 > rngr
        amrh2 = rngr + np.argmax(sum_r2[rngr:])  # argmax nime dovom im2
        refx1 = np.asarray(im1gray[amr1, :]).astype('float64')  # first image
        refx1 = refx1 - np.average(refx1)  # normalize
        refx2 = np.asarray(im2gray[amrh2, :]).astype('float64')  # second image
        refx2 = refx2 - np.average(refx2)  # normalize
        yy = im1gray.shape[0] - (amr1 - rngr)
        r1 = np.empty((yy, 2))

        for i in range(yy):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .


        .
        .
        .


        for i in range(rngr):
            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(6):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

            for j in range(5):
                .
                .
                .

            .
            .
            .

        .
        .
        .

    cdef double min_x,
    cdef double[:,:] rx
    cdef int dx, dx_y
    if min_x1 < min_x2:
        min_x = min_x1
        rx = rx1
        dx = dx1
        dx_y = int(rx_y1)
    else:
        min_x = min_x2
        rx = rx2
        dx = dx2
        dx_y = int(rx_y2)
    cdef double D
    cdef int Dx, Dy
    D = min(min_x, min_y)
    if D == min_x:
        Dx = dx
        Dy = dx_y

    elif D == min_y:
        Dy = dy
        Dx = dy_x

    return int(Dx), int(Dy)
```

Comment: how do you measure time? Does cython need/perform some on-the-fly environment initialization or just-in-time-compilation stuff? If yes, is it included in your measurement and are you able to perform this once before you actual measurement?

Comment: At some 270 lines, with a lot of the code cut out and what appears to be a lot of copy-pasting, what this needs most of all is some (or rather, a lot of) refactoring. Then, add back all the parts you replaced with dots.

Comment: The only thing that typed memoryviews really speed up is indexing individual elements. You aren't doing this. Therefore you're just adding work doing pointless type-checking